# Can I nest Parallel.Invoke methods?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task, task-parallel-library

I was wondering whether it's possible or recommended to have multiple layers of the `Parallel.Invoke` method or whether it is likely to cause problems / slow the application.

Is there a best practice for this?

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => Invoke("orange"),
    () => Invoke("apples"),
    () => Invoke("pears")
);           

public static void Invoke(string name)
{
    Parallel.Invoke(
        () => test.testapp(name),
        () => test.testapp(name),
        () => test.testapp(name)
    );
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this related topic can answer your question? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/14/is-it-ok-to-use-nested-parallel-for-loops/ - I also took the liberty of rewording your question title, as "nest" is probably a term that is more commonly used for this.

Comment: "Is there a best practice for this?" - yes, don't believe that any programming practice/tool/library is a silver bullet that can be judged in the abstract and declared universally "best".

Comment: `I was wondering whether it's possible` What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible. I think the best question is whether this will adversely affect performance, for instance that the inner loop will starve the outer, or vice versa, or that both of them will assume they have the whole CPU available, all its cores. The article I linked to seems to indicate that this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but there might be no benefit - it really depends on what those jobs are doing.

It might be beneficial if they're essentially asynchronous tasks (e.g. on the database or external API) which can be executed in parallel. However, if they're CPU-intensive tasks then you're probably just going to give extra work to the scheduler for no real benefit.

There's an article [here](https://www.guyellisrocks.com/2010/10/nested-parallelforeach.html) which contains some benchmarks using the Parallel libary, it might give you a good idea when to use this.

Results of this test:

Simulating calling external resources:

```
Not Nested: 00:00:14.6155628
Nested: 00:00:09.0907248
```

CPU intensive tasks:

```
Not Nested: 00:00:05.6169188
Nested: 00:00:06.1500767
```

Comment: A different aspect is if an application parallelizes calls to a library, and this library internally uses the same parallelization techniques, such as the ones in the question, will one end adversely affect the other, and I think the answer is no. Whether it makes sense to over-parallelize CPU-bound tasks is another matter though, as you show here.

Comment: @user552769 please accept the answer if it answered your question